# how can i transfer byte object to string with ending '\x0' in python?

Tags: python, utf-8, decode

I have a byte object, i want to translate it into string.

please see this pandas dataframe:

```
In [19]: a
Out[19]: 
                                tk         sec    usec      bp1      bp2      bp3      bp4      bp5      ap1      ap2  ...  as1  as2  as3  as4  as5       lp           amt  ls     vol     oi
0                        b'ZN2106'  1619743523  646104  21920.0  21915.0  21910.0  21905.0  21900.0  21930.0  21935.0  ...   11    5    3    8    3  21930.0  1.642792e+10   0  149210  96841
1         b'ZN2106\x0010250\x0009'  1619744401  684254  21935.0  21930.0  21925.0  21920.0  21910.0  21940.0  21945.0  ...    1    8    3    3   17  21940.0  1.642990e+10   0  149228  96843
2          b'ZN2106\x0016750\x009'  1619744402  319044  21940.0  21935.0  21930.0  21925.0  21920.0  21945.0  21950.0  ...    1    1    6    1   13  21940.0  1.643615e+10   0  149285  96829
3         b'ZN2106\x0014750\x0009'  1619744403  422966  21945.0  21940.0  21935.0  21930.0  21925.0  21950.0  21955.0  ...    7    5   11    4   15  21940.0  1.644120e+10   0  149331  96838
4          b'ZN2106\x0012750\x002'  1619744403  883381  21945.0  21940.0  21935.0  21930.0  21925.0  21955.0  21960.0  ...    3    7    6   16   59  21950.0  1.644647e+10   0  149379  96846
...                            ...         ...     ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...      ...           ...  ..     ...    ...
20343      b'ZN2106\x0067000\x009'  1619765999  791039  21795.0  21790.0  21785.0  21780.0  21775.0  21800.0  21805.0  ...   95   12    2   11   14  21795.0  2.768403e+10   0  252355  85339
20344  b'ZN2106\x0061000\x00\x000'  1619766000  302063  21795.0  21790.0  21785.0  21780.0  21775.0  21800.0  21805.0  ...   93   13    2   11   14  21800.0  2.768424e+10   0  252357  85339
20345     b'ZN2106\x0013750\x0010'  1619766000  781186  21795.0  21790.0  21785.0  21780.0  21775.0  21800.0  21805.0  ...   93   13    2   11   14  21795.0  2.768435e+10   0  252358  85338
20346      b'ZN2106\x0019000\x009'  1619766001  317317  21795.0  21790.0  21785.0  21780.0  21775.0  21800.0  21805.0  ...   92   13    2   11   14  21795.0  2.768490e+10   0  252363  85338
20347           b'ZN2106\x0019000'  1619766002  518211  21795.0  21790.0  21785.0  21780.0  21775.0  21800.0  21805.0  ...   92   13    2   11   14  21795.0  2.768490e+10   0  252363  85338

[20348 rows x 28 columns]
```

the columns `tk` is the byte object, i want to make it as string.

I had tried:

```
df['tk'].str.decode('uft-8')
```

but i got:

```
In [17]: a['tk'].str.decode('utf-8')
Out[17]: 
0                 ZN2106
1        ZN21061025009
2         ZN2106167509
3        ZN21061475009
4         ZN2106127502
              ...       
20343     ZN2106670009
20344    ZN2106610000
20345    ZN21061375010
20346     ZN2106190009
20347       ZN210619000
Name: tk, Length: 20348, dtype: object
```

This is not what i want, as you can see, the second row,

what i want is `ZN2106`, but it return me 'ZN21061025009'

it ignores string ending '\x0', how can i solve this?

Comment: Split it at `b'\x0'` and decode only the first part?

Comment: @mkrieger1 yes, only the first

Comment: Sorry, I meant that as a suggestion. Have you tried to do that?

Comment: Start at `b'ZN2106\x0010250\x0009'.decode('uft-8').split('\x00')` it returns a list object `['ZN2106', '10250', '09']` and for the 1st line `b'ZN2106'.decode().split('\x00')` returns a list as well `['ZN2106']`…

Answer (score 0):

Try `apply`:

```py
import pandas as pd
a = pd.DataFrame([b'ZN2106',b'ZN2106\x0010250\x0009'],columns=['tk'])
print(a)
print()
print(a['tk'].apply(lambda x: x.decode('utf8').split('\x00')[0]))
```

Output:

```
                         tk
0                 b'ZN2106'
1  b'ZN2106\x0010250\x0009'

0    ZN2106
1    ZN2106
Name: tk, dtype: object
```